# ajax POST in ajax succes not doing anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've got a button on which the user can click which then will fire an ajax call and when it is succes I want to fire another ajax call. 
I've tried it like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'send_confirm.php',
            data: {
                f_name: f_name, 
                l_name: l_name,
                email: email,
                bedrijf: bedrijf,
                first: first,
                second: second,
                third: third,
                fourth: fourth
            },
            success: function(res) {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: 'send_mail.php',
                    data2 :{
                        name: name,
                        email: email,
                        first: first,
                        second: second,
                        third: third,
                        fourth: fourth
                    },
                    succes: function(res){
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

The first ajax call DOES return succes because when I `console.log(res)` it does return the `json_encode`
but after the console.log / when i've removed the console.log. The SECOND ajax call wont fire (I think? It doesn't show `Navigated to..` in the console.log and the page remains the same / no callback or anything)

Comment: Can you test the second ajax call in isolation of the first to ensure it is working?

Comment: You mean testin it outside of the first ajax call?

Comment: Yes - otherwise you're looking at a false negative result.

Comment: I recommend you to launch the send_mail.php script as a server-side call (from your `send_confirm.php` script) instead of doing that from your 1st ajax response

Comment: Are you trying to use php's `header("Location: XXX")` to redirect? (at send_mail.php)

Comment: @StabDev look at the answer I wrote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the callback as "success" and not "succes" (according to the code you attached it's just a misprint)

Comment: Oh.. well.. this worked.. This is so stupid. Stupid typo. Thanks! Im a bit embarrassed

Comment: @StabDev If the answer helped you, upvote it, so other people will see you found a solution

Comment: I cant upvote it because I dont have 15 reputation. But i'll accept it :)

Comment: @StabDev yea sorry, thats what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two wrong words

You should call the callback as "`data`" and not "`data2`" and  "`success`" and not "`succes`" (according to the code you attached it's wrong words in your script