# Success, failure not called Ajax call to C# function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I've been sitting on a problem and I can't figure out why the problem is even there.

The problem is that I'm calling C# function via Ajax post.

The javascript code is

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Home/LogIn",
    data: { userName: username, password: password },
    dataType: 'json',
    succes: function (data) {
        alert(data.d + '  Succes')
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        alert(data.d + '  failure');
    }
});
```

And the C# function code is

```
public string LogIn(string userName, string password)
{
    LogInController loginController = (LogInController)Session["LogInController"];

    User tempuser = loginController.CheckLogin(password, userName);

    if (tempuser != null)
    {
        massdrop = new MassdropShop(tempuser);
        Session["LoggedInName"] = tempuser.Name;
        Session["massdrop"] = massdrop;
        return "1";
    }
    else
        return "0";
}
```

When I run this code, it triggers the C# function, the C# function does it's job and everything's fine. But for some reason the Success and Failure function aren't running.

Is there anyone who could enlighten me to what I'm doing wrong?

Greetings,

Bram

Comment: Instead of returning `string` return `Json` from controller method as your ajax call is expecting Json in return.

Comment: View the console in your browser and heed Kartikeya's comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax POST in ajax succes not doing anything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608987/ajax-post-in-ajax-succes-not-doing-anything)

Comment: In addition to AngelofDemons answer, shouldn't "failure" property actually be "error"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `success` instead of `succes`. I've had the same issue

```
        succes: function (data) {
        alert(data.d + '  Succes')
    },
```

should be

```
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d + '  Succes')
    },
```

Hope this solves the problem, if not comment and I'll take a closer look at it!

Answer (score -1):

try this
in this line

```
data:{ userName: username, password: password },

change
data:JSON.stringify{ userName: username, password: password },
success: function (data) {


            alert(JSON.stringify(data.d));
```

Comment: Why post the exact same answer?